# distorm - how to find out if operand(s) of an assembly instruction are affected by ASLR (relocation section)

Tags: assembly, x86, disassembly, portable-executable, relocation

I'm using the [distorm disassembler](https://code.google.com/p/distorm/) for portable executables (PEs) on a x86 platform. Is there any existing function, macro or flag that can indicate if any of the operands of an assembly instruction are affected by the relocation section?